# Post requests not showing correct content in response with Requests module in Python 3

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm currently trying to create a python script to login on my DVWA with a given user and password but am having trouble with the response from the post request. The 2 pictures attached will explain it much better, but in short, "Login failed" is not showing up in the response content but on the website it is, why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bic94.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MfE9.png

My Code:

````
import requests
import time

userna = input("Username: ")
passw = input("Password: ")

target_url = "http://localhost/dvwa/login.php"
data_dict = {"username": userna,"password": passw, "Login": "submit"}
response = requests.post(target_url, data=data_dict)

if 'Login failed' not in response.content.decode():
    print("success!")
else:
    print("login failed")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue but I think I know what your issue is. It's not showing you 'Login Failed' because the form isn't getting submitted. The form isn't getting submitted because you're missing parameters for the login request. If you ever have a form, you can try a GET request instead of a POST request and it should give you the parameters required for submission. If they change, you'll have to collect those parameters dynamically. Our DVWA login form requires two more fields which haven't been included. They are "Login:Login" and "user_token:this changes each session".

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

target_url = 'http://localhost/login.php'
s = requests.Session()
username = str(input('Username: '))
password = str(input('Password: '))
user_token = '*'
Login = 'Login'
data_dict = {'username':username,'password':password,'Login':'Login','user_token':user_token}
temp = []
initial_response = s.get(target_url)

for key, value in data_dict.items():
    if '*' != value:
        temp.append([key, value])
    else:
        print('finding the value of', key)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(initial_response.text, 'html.parser')
        found_value = soup.find('input', {'name':key})['value']
        print('it is: ', found_value)
        temp.append([key, found_value])

z = dict(temp)
p = s.post(target_url, data = z)

print(p.url)
if p.url != target_url:
    print('login success!')
else:
    print('login failed!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be working now. How did you find those 2 extra fields?

Comment: @Swifty I think the most important part of this is using a session